# Is there any Python library for delay differential equations (DDE) supporting Python 3.8?

Tags: python, differential-equations

The library `pydelay` is outdated and has not been updated for years. Is there any Python library for delay differential equations (DDE) supporting Python 3.8? Or is there any introduction of DDE solution by SciPy?

Comment: Please read about what's on-topic in the [help/on-topic]. Questions asking us to find or recommend an off-site resource, like a library, are explicitly _off-topic_.

Comment: I will happily answer your question on [softwarerecs.se] (possibly with my own library), but before you ask there, please specify what you need: Is efficiency a relevant issue for you? Do you need any specific features like state-dependent delays?

Comment: I feel sorry, I thought this question is based on open sources and does not involve commercial purposes. I did not mean to violate the guideline.

Answer (score 1):

The module `ddeint` is most likely what you're looking for. Just

```
pip install ddeint
```

and the module should work fine.