Is there a way to solve system of ODEs with scipy solve_ivp introducing delay to one of the components?
I would be really thankful for some suggestions how to introduce a delay in one of my ODE in the system and solve it with solve_ivp scipy.
So, I have a system of equations with some analytical functions f1(t), f2(t), f3(t), f4(t) that I pass to solve_ivp function.
def model_step(t,
           y,
           w_0, w_1, w_2, w_3, w_4, w_5, w_6, w_7, w_8, w_9, w_10,
           tau_0, tau_1, tau_2, tau_3,
           threshold,
           power,
           q,
           i_0, i_1, i_2, i_3
           ):
"""
Builds differential equation model
"""

        
f_e, f_p, f_s, f_v = y

ff_e = (min(max((i_0 + w_0 * f_e + w_1 * f1(t) + w_2 * f_p + w_3 * f_s), threshold), 25))
ff_p = (min(max((i_1 + w_4 * f_e + f2(t)), threshold), 25))
ff_s = (min(max((i_2 + w_5 * f_e + w_6 * f3(t) - w_7 * f_v), threshold), 25))
ff_v = (min(max((i_3 + w_8 * f_e - w_9 * f_s +  w_10 * f4(t)), threshold), 25))

    
df_edt = ((q * ff_e ** power) - f_e) / tau_0
df_pdt = ((q * ff_p ** power) - f_p) / tau_1
df_sdt = ((q * ff_s ** power) - f_s) / tau_2
df_vdt = ((q * ff_v ** power) - f_v) / tau_3


dydt = [df_edt, df_pdt, df_sdt, df_vdt]

return dydt

I would like to add a delay to an input to ff_s from f_e to make it like:
ff_s = (min(max((i_2 + w_5 * f_e(t-delay) + w_6 * f3(t) - w_7 * f_v), threshold), 25))

For now, as I understand correctly each solution is calculated directly from the previous timepoint solution (part where f_e, f_p, f_s, f_v = y).
Is it possible to somehow return a history of all previous timepoints or in other way introduce delay?
I have tried to search in the related topics at stackoverflow and did not find an answer.

Don’t you mean ‘f_e(t-delay)’ - otherwise you are using a value before computing it?

The tricky thing about this problem is that solve_ivp is using an adaptive stepsize. e.g. it will try a step size of t_delta=0.1, and estimate the error. Then it will try a step size of 0.05 if that resulted in too much error. So, it's very likely that it never evaluated your function at the point t + delay, unless delay happens to coincidentally match up with the adaptive step size.

Maybe using scipy.integrate.ode? Using that gives you more control, though it will be slower since you have to manually step it.

@lastchance, yes, sure, you are right. Thanks for a correction, I will edit my post.

@NickODell, thanks, yes that is a tricky part. But, if there is a full "dense" history of points I can try to interpolate it to get values of my specific timepoints.

It is not too bad to write your own Runge-Kutta timestepper, @Yehor K. That will allow you complete control over previous values. Although you will still have the issue of what to do at the start (or, indeed, for any t<delay).

@jared, Thank you! I will check documentation for it.

@lastchance : This is the wrong approach for a fast solution. In opposition, take the well-functioning time-stepper classes (RK45 etc.) of solve_ivp, and build your own time loop from them. Each stepper provides a "dense output" polynomial interpolation, you would have to take from the solve_ivp loop how they can be combined into a piecewise polynomial interpolation object. One need to limit the step size to be smaller than the delay.

Solving delay-differential equations based on the scipy methods is not a new question, there was pydelay which seems outdated, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19457673/python-solve-delay-differential-equations-conditionally, and some more recent effort with ddeint, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62649215/is-there-any-python-library-for-delay-differential-equations-dde-supporting-py

@LutzLehman, Thank you! I will take a look on existing things and try to build own time loop if nothing works for me.
